# VHDL 2008 Width mismatch

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I am facing a width mismatch issue when I am using a 3-dimensional array using VHDL.
Error is :

```
[Synth 8-549] port width mismatch for port 'KERNEL_OUT[0]': port width = 16, actual width = 32 ["C:/project_2/src/top.vhd":29]
```

As we can see that line #30 is actually 32 bits and the component is having an unconstrained port. So instead of taking the length from the connected port, it using the value from previously instantiated component.

I've made a very minimal design out of it. I'm using Vivado 2018.2 There are high chances that this might be a tool issue. But it will be very much helpful if someone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

top.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use work.style_pack.all;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Entity
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity top is
  port(
    dummy : in std_logic
    );

end entity top;

architecture arch_top of top is
  signal KernelInt1 : StdVectorArrayTp(0 to 4)(15 downto 0);
  signal KernelInt2 : StdVectorArrayTp(0 to 4)(31 downto 0);
begin
  --
  INST_pixel_to_matrix_1 : entity work.pixel_to_matrix
    port map (
      KERNEL_OUT => KernelInt1
      );
  --
  INST_pixel_to_matrix_2 : entity work.pixel_to_matrix
    port map (
      KERNEL_OUT => KernelInt2
      );
end architecture arch_top;
```

pixel_to_matrix.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

 
-----------------------
-- ENTITY DEFINITION --
-----------------------
entity pixel_to_matrix is
  port (
    KERNEL_OUT : out StdVectorArrayTp
    );
end pixel_to_matrix;


architecture arch_pixel_to_matrix of pixel_to_matrix is
begin

end architecture arch_pixel_to_matrix;
```

style_pack.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;


package style_pack is

  type StdVectorArrayTp is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector;

end style_pack;

package body style_pack is


end style_pack;
```

I've posted same question at https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/VHDL-2008-width-mismatch-on-multiple-instantiations/td-p/1164467

where I uploaded the code with Vivado project https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/SYNTHBD/36597/2/project_1.zip

Edit :

Project with 3D array  StdVectorArrayTp https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/SYNTHBD/36602/1/project_2.zip

Comment: Vivado had a lot of vhdl2008 fixes in vivado 2019, particularly 2019.2. Have you tried a more up to date version? (Maybe 2020.1?)

Comment: Tried in Vivado 2019.1. We actually went back to 2019.1 because of some vendor IP issues.  I simply added some generics to the pixel_to_matrix and didn't use them, Vivado didn't throw an error.

Comment: @user1155120 looks like a tool bug, then. But why isn't the code here a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: This looks like the particular version of Vivado can't reach deep enough to provide the subtype constraint from the actual. The code in the zip file will analyze, elaborate and simulate with a recent version of ghdl, It appears valid. UG901 in various Vivado releases offer no insight which indicates you'd be dependent on a bug fix.

Comment: @user1155120 I added some dummy generics, then there were no issues. I thought about deep arrays. I will edit the question to include 3D array.

Comment: @Tricky Same behaviour with 2020.1

Comment: @Tricky I got a response from Xilinx saying that this is indeed a bug and fixed in the upcoming 2020.2 release.

Comment: @user1155120 I got a response from Xilinx saying that this is indeed a bug and fixed in the upcoming 2020.2 release.